# Is it possible to multipurpose a Twig template?

Tags: php, templates, twig, slim, phpactiverecord

I am learning to use Slim framework and Twig. I want to know if it is possible to kind of multi-purpose a template.

Consider this; I want to make a form to add a job for a client, if you access via the 'job/new' route it would output a select list of clients to choose a client for whom the job is intended.

If however, you access via the 'job/new/:id' route it would render the same template but with only the client that the 'id' value corresponds to.

```
        {% for client in clients %}
        <option value="{{ client.id }}">{{ client.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
```

The above will work when I use:

```
     $data['clients'] = Client::find('all');
     $app->render('job/new.html',$data);
```

However, in my other route:

```
     $data['clients'] = Client::find($id);
     $app->render('job/new.html',$data);
```

As there is only 1 record it does not seem to output. I just wanted to save pulling all clients and multi-purpose the same template.

If this is not possible I know that I can pull all clients and send in the ID to select the client on the second route, or, create a different template that does not use the select and just send the single client to it.

Thanks

Comment: What's the result of the `::find('all')` and the `::find($id)`? The first is an array that's okay, but the second one isn't just a "single element"?

Comment: Ah, dumb head on this morning. $data['clients'] = array(Client::find($id)) ;will allow me to do this. It's not pretty for sure. Thanks for waking me up Gerifield.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to suggest and no problem. :)

Comment: Do you want to answer and I'll accept your answer. You nudged me to it. ;)

Comment: Okay, thanks! (That was my idea too. :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I post the correct answer here, not just in the comments.

The `Client::find('all');` gives back an array of elements, but the `Client::find($id);` gives only a single element.
If you want to use the same template with the iteration you have to put the result into an array like this: `$data['clients'] = array(Client::find($id));`